# How to filter specific key values from array based on the other key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, angularjs, filter

I am having an array with name of the product and its storage

```
let array = [{name: "samsung A", storage: "128GB"}, {name: "samsung B", storage: "128GB"}, {name: "samsung C", storage: "256GB"}, {name: "samsung A", storage: "256GB"}]
```

I have another array  which has all the names which needed storage let array be

```
let array1 = ["samsung A", "samsung B", "samsung C"]
```

Comparing the above 2 arrays i want to map each key what are the available storages.

I have tried with

```
array.filter(el => el.name === "samsung A").map(item => item.storage)
```

But in the above i manually given "samsung A" but i want to get all the storages available in array from all  the keys available in array2

Comment: Sorry I am not able to understand the question. You want to return an array of storage matching with array2 from array 1

Comment: yes, want to filter all the storages available for the specific brand name available in array2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be:

1. Loop over all the phones you want to have (previous called array2)
2. Filter out your original data set by the name of that phone
3. Get all storages from the different data sets
4. Add this new value to the result

```js
let data = [{name: "samsung A", storage: "128GB"}, {name: "samsung B", storage: "128GB"}, {name: "samsung C", storage: "256GB"}, {name: "samsung A", storage: "256GB"}]

let phones = ["samsung A", "samsung B", "samsung C"]

let result = [];

// Loop all phones
phones.forEach(phone => {
  // Get all data by name
  let filteredData = data.filter(d => d.name === phone)
  
  // Map all storages
  let storages  = filteredData.map(fd => fd.storage)
  
  // Create result
  let entry = {name: phone, storages: storages}
  
  result.push(entry)
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

To start off, you will need a `storage` map, which maps each device to an array of storage capacities, e.g. `{'samsung A': ['128GB', '256GB'] }`.

Then, for each product name in `array1` (i.e. `"samsung A", "samsung B", "samsung C"`), get the corresponding `storage` value(s) in `array` (i.e. filter `array1` to all the keys named after the value on the current iteration and map them to an array).

In the end, you add a new entry to the `storage` map which the array returned from the step above.

```js
let storage = {};
array1.forEach(product => {
    let storages = array.filter(item => item.name === product).map(item => item.storage);
    storage[product] = storages;
})
```

You can also use `.reduce`:

```js
let storage = array1.reduce((acc, product) => {
    acc[product] = array.filter(item => item.name === product).map(item => item.storage);
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding

```js
let array = [{name: "samsung A", storage: "128GB"}, {name: "samsung B", storage: "128GB"}, {name: "samsung C", storage: "256GB"}, {name: "samsung A", storage: "256GB"}]

let array1 = ["samsung A", "samsung B", "samsung C"]
let finalArray = []

let storageArray = array.filter((x)=>array1.includes(x.name)).map((y)=>{
   let index = finalArray.findIndex((m)=>m.name === y.name)
  if(index >=0){
    finalArray[index].storage.push(y.storage)
  }else{
      finalArray.push({name: y.name, storage:[y.storage]})
  }
})

console.log(finalArray)
```

Comment: *Comparing the above 2 arrays i want to map each key what are the available storages.* You did not do this, you just give an array with the storages.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, Please check the answer above, considering loops used it is more efficient.

Comment: This indeed works but isn't the most performant. However, I removed the downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

At the first run map on array1 and then filter on array

```
let result = []
  array1.map(arr => {
    let temp = array.filter(el => el.name === arr).map(item => item.storage)
    result.push({name:arr, storages:temp})
  })
  console.log(result);
```

Comment: It seems like you want to filter specific key values from an array based on the values of another key. Your code looks mostly correct, but there's a minor issue with the filtering logic. You need to check if the name property of the elements in array matches with the current element arr from array1. Here's the corrected version of your code:

let result = [];
array1.forEach(arr => {
  let temp = array.filter(el => el.name === arr).map(item => item.storage);
  result.push({ name: arr, storages: temp });
});
console.log(result);